# Finding the closest, previous element with specific data attribute jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This has been troubling me for the passed few hours now.

I have a table. Within that table i'm looking for the closest, previous table row with a specific data attribute. I'm doing this search right after a successful use of jquery sortable. I've tried almost everything and it ALWAYS comes up with the wrong thing.

Here's what i'm using

```
var newIndex = ui.item.index();
var menuLevel = parseInt($("#menu-table").find("[data-menu-nesting='" + newIndex + "']").attr("data-menu-level"));
var menuId = $("#menu-table").find("[data-menu-nesting='" + newIndex + "']").attr("data-menu-id");

if (menuLevel == 2) {
    var findAboveRowName = $(".menu-table-rows[data-menu-nesting='" + newIndex + "']").prev(".menu-table-rows").data("menu-level","1").attr("data-menu-name");
    alert(findAboveRowName);    
}
if (menuLevel == 3) {
    var findAboveRowName = $(".menu-table-rows[data-menu-nesting='" + newIndex + "']").prev(".menu-table-rows").data("menu-level","2").attr("data-menu-name");
    alert(findAboveRowName);    
}
```

Essentially, the variable "newIndex" is supposed to grab the new position of the row after being sorted, menuLevel is supposed to grab the data attribute "menu-level" of that table row, and menuId is grabbing another data attribute of that table row.

It's specifically looking for the nearest, previous menu-level attribute in the table rows.  So if a table row with a menu-level attribute of 2 is moved, it's looking for the nearest table row with a menu-level attribute of 1.

The full jquery sortable script i'm using if needed

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
                update: function(event, ui) {
                    var serial = $('#sortable').sortable('serialize');
                    var newIndex = ui.item.index();
                    var menuLevel = parseInt($("#menu-table").find("[data-menu-nesting='" + newIndex + "']").attr("data-menu-level"));
                    var menuId = $("#menu-table").find("[data-menu-nesting='" + newIndex + "']").attr("data-menu-id");
                    if (menuLevel == 2) {
                        var findAboveRowName = $(".menu-table-rows[data-menu-nesting='" + newIndex + "']").prev(".menu-table-rows").data("menu-level","1").attr("data-menu-name");
                        alert(findAboveRowName);
                        // $.post("./menu-controller.php", { adjustParent: true, id: menuId, parent: findAboveRowName });
                    }
                    if (menuLevel == 3) {
                        var findAboveRowName = $(".menu-table-rows[data-menu-nesting='" + newIndex + "']").prev(".menu-table-rows").data("menu-level","2").attr("data-menu-name");
                        alert(findAboveRowName);
                        // $.post("./menu-controller.php", { adjustParent: true, id: menuId, parent: findAboveRowName });
                    }
                    $.ajax({
                    url: "./menu-controller.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: serial,
                    success: function() {
                        $("#sortable").load("./menu-manager.php #menu-table", function() {
                            $.get('./menu-admin.js');
                        });
                },
                    error: function(){
                        alert("A problem occurred when moving this menu item. Please try again or contact support.");
                    }
                    });
                },
            handle:'.move-item',
            connectWith:'#menu-table',
            placeholder: "highlight",
            containment: "parent",
            revert: true,
            tolerance: "pointer",
            items: 'tbody > *'
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uf2H7/2/)

Comment: isn't $("selector").parent("tr[data=value]") one way to go?

Comment: Could you explain what I'm supposed to do in the fiddle to see the problem? It's alerting things; if they're wrong, I don't know what the right alerts should be.

Comment: Move "Sub-Submenu 2" under "Submenu 3". It will alert saying "home". That's not correct because after moving "Sub-Submenu 2" under "Submenu 3", the nearest lower level menu item would be "Submenu 3", not "home".

Answer (score 2):

`.prev` only returns the immediately previous element, it doesn't keep looking for the nearest element that matches the selector. Use `.prevAll` to find all the elements matching a selector, and then use `.first()` to narrow it down to the first one, which is the nearest. And if you want to search for a specific `data-menu-level` attribute, you have to put that in the selector; calling `.data("menu-level", 1)` *sets* the attribute, it doesn't search for it.

```
if (menuLevel == 2) {
    var findAboveRowName = $(".menu-table-rows[data-menu-nesting='" + newIndex + "']").prevAll(".menu-table-rows[data-menu-level=1]").first().data("menu-name");
    alert(findAboveRowName);    
}
```

Comment: For some reason, it's not even collecting the correct menu-level from the row which I believe may be the actual issue. For example, if I move a level 1 item, it alerts me of the findAboveRowName variable even though it's not supposed to do anything if the menu_level is 1.

Comment: Hard for me to know what's going wrong without seeing the relevant HTML. Can you make a fiddle?